# React SWR, how to filter/sort data

Tags: reactjs

I have typical get request

```
const { data } = useSWR(
  ['api/projects', API_KEY],
  fetcher
);
```

And after fetching data I would like to filter items, in my case based on current GPS location.
So how is better to make this?
Like `onSuccess(data, key, config)` store data to my state and after work on filtering?
Or I should use mutations somehow and filter cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter data into a new array and render component basing on this array. Something like this:

```
const { data:projects, error } = useSWR(
    ['api/projects', API_KEY],
    fetcher
);
if(error) return (<ErrorScreen />);
if(!data) return (<Loading />);
let availableProjects = projects.filter(p => availabilityChecker(p.location));
return (
    availableProjects.map(p => (<Project key={p.id} project={p} />));
);
```

Comment: Would this still work for large amounts of data, like 500 plus? Or in that case would it be better to make seperate api calls?